# Developing a single sign on with two different authentication's modes

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, single-sign-on

I'm trying to develope a single sign on with two different authentication mode, I mean, one of the applications has active directory and the another one use a simple login and password, which is the best way to develope it?, using a table in the database which joins active directory and login?. Could you help me?. These two application are developed under vb.net.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use database table. Just keep a separate argument which have two modes - directory and login. I think it will do the trick.